# Having issue on subquery that return more than 1 value

Tags: javascript, sql, vb.net

I look for whole already. just need someone who is sharp eyes to help up. Thanks.

```
    SELECT (Select contactid from [tableA].[dbo].tableC where Company =  '" & company & "' AND empid = vProfile2.EmpNo) as contactid,vprofile2.EmpNo EmpNo, vprofile2.EmpName EmpName, upper(vprofile2.CompanyCode) CompanyCode, upper(vprofile2.DeptName) DeptName, Upper(vprofile2.JobTitle) JobTitle " & _
",Email_add Email,(Select Contact from [tableA].[dbo].tableC where Company =  '" & company & "' AND empid = vProfile2.EmpNo) as contact, " & _
"(Select Speeddial from [tableA].[dbo].tableC where Company =  '" & company & "' AND empid = vProfile2.EmpNo) as Speeddial " & _
"FROM [tableA].[dbo].tableC  RIGHT JOIN server.tableB.[dbo].[tableD] vprofile2 ON vProfile2.EmpNo = tableC.empid " & _
" AND tableC.company=vProfile2.CompanyCode " & _
"Inner JOIN server.tableB.[dbo].[tbEmail] vEmail ON vProfile2.EmpNo= vEmail.Emp_No " & _
  "WHERE(vprofile2.EmpNo Is Not null) And " & _
"vProfile2.CompanyCode = '" & company & "' " & _
 "ORDER by EmpName "
```

I getting an error, and I try to find what's happening.

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <=, >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

Comment: The first thing you need to do is learn about Sql injection and parameterized queries. Then, once your code is safe, you can start working on the sub query problem.

Comment: We have no idea about your table structures, current data, expected results, etc. I'm not at all sure why you're using subqueries at all - it's not an obvious way to structure your query when `tableC` is already in the `FROM` clause and (due to join conditions) constrained to have a `Company` value equal to `company`. Also, echo Zohar's comment, you need to use parameters.

Comment: Show us the processed query, that code is to hard to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It means that you have used a subquery to return the value for a field, and that subquery can be returning more than one record per row:

```
(Select Speeddial from [tableA].[dbo].tableC where Company =  '" & company & "' AND empid = vProfile2.EmpNo) as Speeddial
```

Are you sure that this where clause will return only one (or zero) results for each record in the main query?